# How to declare variables dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

is it possible to read from post variables dynamically? 
i.e.

```
function ajax_edit_color(color_id, building)
{
    var color_name      = $('#color_name_'+color_id).val();
    var color_hex_code  = $('#color_hex_code_'+color_id).val();
    console.log(color_name, color_hex_code);
}
```

when I look at the console, the variables are undefined. Is there a correct syntax for this?

EDIT :
the HTML is dynamic (PHP):

```
<label for="color_name_<?php $value['id']; ?>">Color name : </label>
<input type="text" name="color_name_<?php $value['id']; ?>" id="color_name_<?php $value['id']; ?>" class="form-control" required="required" value="<?php echo $value['color_name']; ?>" />
<label for="color_hex_code_<?php $value['id']; ?>">Color HEX code : </label>
<input type="text" name="color_hex_code_<?php $value['id']; ?>" id="color_hex_code_<?php $value['id']; ?>" class="form-control" required="required" value="<?php echo $value['color_code']; ?>" />
```

AND HERE's the rendered HTML :

```
<label for="color_name_">Color name : </label>
<input type="text" name="color_name_6" id="color_name_" class="form-control" required="required" value="orange" />
<label for="color_hex_code_">Color HEX code : </label>
<input type="text" name="color_hex_code_6" id="color_hex_code_" class="form-control" required="required" value="ff9c00" />
```

Comment: Which variable is `undefined`? If `color_name` and `color_hex_code` then check if you have on your page elements with ids `color_name` + `color_id`.

Comment: The *variables* aren't undefined, their *values* are. This also sounds like the entirely wrong approach to whatever you're trying to do here. If you have elements with numbered ids, you're probably rather looking for classes and/or directly attached event handlers instead.

Comment: What is the value of color_id? and please add HTML code

Comment: When you are looking  from the console itself, you are looking in a different scope. Those variables are only defined in the context of that *particular* invocation of `ajax_edit_color`... if you want them to be declared at a higher scope: *declare them at a higher scope*

Comment: I have page elements with id's i.e. color_name_5 and color_hex_code_5 with their values set. How can I retrieve them in my JS?

Comment: can you post you html code and how you call ajax_edit_color ?

Comment: @dujmovicv if `color_id` is `5`, then that should already work. Are you sure  they have the `id` of `color_name_5`, as opposed to the `name` of `color_name_5`? (names  and ids are not the same thing)

Comment: Variable shows `undefined` because while calling the function, you are passing `undefined`.  I will suggest you please use console.log for variables before passing the value to function, You will get understand what is exactly the problem

Comment: re your edit showing the php: the actual html rendered would be more useful, to be honest

Comment: the HTML is up in the EDITED question

Comment: @dujmovicv no, the php is in the EDITED question.

Comment: and now, there is the rendered HTML also

Comment: @dujmovicv and did you notice anything when you looked at the rendered html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your final HTML:

```
<label for="color_name_">Color name : </label>
<input type="text" name="color_name_6" id="color_name_"
    class="form-control" required="required" value="orange" />
```

The name is right, but the id is wrong. Fix your php, and the javascript will start working. The id needs to be `color_name_6`, not `color_name_`.

Comment: that happens when you are confident in your PHP code and start blaming the JS... THNX

Comment: @dujmovicv easily done - which is exactly why I was very careful about asking for the final html,  not just the php ;p We've all  been in this position (maybe not with php, or jquery, or whatever - but the general theme of the problem being far removed from where we're focusing)

Answer (score 0):

Your basic approach is correct, so I suggest you start with a simplified test, for example without PHP. One basic example, which I verified to work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>  
    <script>
        function test(){
            var index=1;
            var val=$("#color_name_"+index).val();
            console.log( '****' +val);
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="test();return false;">test</button>
    <input type="text" id='color_name_1' value='green'>
    <input type="text" id='color_name_2' value='blue'>
</body>
```

This works. Now if your own code is failing, try looking for differences, in particular:
1. When is your javascript running - could it be before the "color_name" elements are rendered in the document?
2. Could your PHP be generating wrong values, this could be tested by viewing the document source of course

Answer (score -1):

edit you javascript to match the following

```
function ajax_edit_color(color_id, building)
{
var color_name      = $('#'+color_id).val();
var color_hex_code  = $('#'+color_id).val();
console.log(color_name, color_hex_code);
}
```

//color_name_ and color_hex_code_ are both already part of your ids.

Comment: How are you calling that function and what values are you passing in